# Flex on parent div affecting flex of child buttons

Tags: html, css

I have two buttons that I want side by side with a little space between them:

[image]

I originally did this by using `display: flex;` and `justify-content: space-between;`.

But, I want the block that wraps the two buttons to be horizontally and vertically centered on a full page. Therefore, I wrapped everything in a parent div and applied `display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center` to the parent div. However, this results in the spacing of the buttons being reset.

[image]

How do I get the overall block to be horizontally and vertically centered on the page while also keeping the spacing of the buttons?

The code is here and [here is a Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cqgaLspf/).

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-wrap">
  <div class="button-wrap">
    <button class="button">
       Button 1
    </button>
    <button class="button">
      Button 2
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.form-wrap {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  max-width: 100vw;
  width: 100vw;
  max-height: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
  
}

.button-wrap {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  max-width: 200px;
}

.button {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button:hover {
  background: lightyellow;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add a margin to your button elements.

```css
.form-wrap {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  max-width: 100vw;
  width: 100vw;
  max-height: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
  
}

.button-wrap {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  max-width: 200px;
}

.button {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin:0 15px;
}

.button:hover {
  background: lightyellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-wrap">
  <div class="button-wrap">
    <button class="button">
       Button 1
    </button>
    <button class="button">
      Button 2
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Solution #2: Or you can set a width to your button-wrap element that is larger than the total width of the 2 buttons, then you will have a space between the 2 buttons, like below snippet:

```css
.form-wrap {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  max-width: 100vw;
  width: 100vw;
  max-height: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
  
}

.button-wrap {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width:250px;max-width: 250px;
}

.button {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button:hover {
  background: lightyellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-wrap">
  <div class="button-wrap">
    <button class="button">
       Button 1
    </button>
    <button class="button">
      Button 2
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In your first solution you might want to remove the '.button-wrap { max-width: 200px;}' since that's forcing the buttons to shrink (the numbers are on the second line) And instead of giving both buttons an inline-margin, a way without 'unnecessary margins' would be to target only the first button with '.button:first-of-type' and give that a 'margin-right'

Comment: @Corrl thank you, I agreee; that was original CSS from OP so I left it there for now.